# Will the inner bean created as per the question?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

If the outer bean is prototype and the inner bean is singleton, then when the ApplicationContext is initialized, the question is will the inner bean be created at that time?

Can anyone explain what will be the answer of this question?

Also

If the outer bean is singleton and the inner bean is prototype, then when the ApplicationContext is initialized, the question is will the inner bean be created at that time?

why and why not?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I am unable to understand it.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer - if that's the case, you should not be conceptualizing about these details. Learning about Javabeans and design patterns (Singleton) is a bit out of scope for someone who cannot understand how to write the code that implements these concepts (your words).

Comment: what should I do? I feel so dumb.

Comment: @RandyCasburn suggest me what should i do

Comment: [Start here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and go through the all 7 tutorials under _Trails Covering the Basics_

Comment: @RandyCasburn I think it will not create bean in case if the outer bean is prototype cause they are created only if you call the get bean method.